# Using ASP.NET MVC 3 **WITHOUT** jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, javascript

I need to write an application in ASP.NET MVC, but for corporate reasons I can't use jQuery.  I have heard that you can "turn off" jQuery and that ASP.NET controls like TextBoxFor will fall back to using Microsoft's older JS libraries.  But I haven't found any detailed information on how to do this.

Anyone have experience with this approach?  Any pointers?

Comment: Gotta love corporate environments.

Comment: i can understand (sort of), no javascript. how that then subverts to no jquery reeks of corporate misunderstanding and total ignorance (imho). but hey, there's gold in them there (blighted) hills

Answer (score 9):

ASP.NET MVC does not require jQuery. The MVC3 project templates include it in `_Layout.cshtml` because many developers prefer it. You can remove it.

It does use jQuery Validation by default, however, but you can use the Microsoft Ajax MVC2 libraries instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove jQuery scripts, you will be unable to use the jQuery/Unobtrusive MVC 3 validation.

Use the MS scripts and corresponding validation functionality instead:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
"~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"

"~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js"
```

That’s all.

By the way, why cannot you use the jQuery in your project?

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-). In my case the 'conservative' company I work for does not want to depend on any plugins, therefore we have to write everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It's all down to the adapters that you decide to include from the default script folders. If you don't want to use Jquery include the other adapter files.